# How do I access a Firestore Collection in a Nuxt 3 Server Route, Utilizing VueFire

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vuefire

I'm building an application that allows a user to render an RSS feed from a Firestore Collection. My solution is to use a [Nuxt Server Route](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-routes) that returns with an XML file rendered via an [RSS feed generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss).

The issue that arises is that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access Firestore within a Server Route. The [documentation](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/nuxt/ssr.html) for VueFire, the handler I'm using to interface with Firebase, states

> "You don't need to do anything special to make it work with SSR, everything is handled automatically."

This simple line has done nothing but vex me, as any of the usual methods of accessing Firestore (`useFirestore()`, `getCurrentUser()`, being two examples), fails with a `(app/no-options)` error.

Here's an example of the code that's failing. I'm basing this code off of the [Middleware Example](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/nuxt/auth.html) in the VueFire documentation.

```
// server/routes/[user]/rss.js
import { useFirestore } from 'vuefire'

export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
    const db = await useFirestore();
})
```

What am I missing here? Why does VueFire fail to initialize in server routes and server routes only? Thanks.

Things I've Tried:

- I used the knowledge from [this repo](https://github.com/chrisspiegl/test-nuxt-vuefire-ssr) to ensure SSR was enabled correctly
- I explored multiple guides for utilizing SSR with Nuxt 3, but all of these on Stack Overflow and beyond ignore the Server Routes system

My final solution will be manually importing Firebase Admin, but that seems counterintuitive to the sentence "You don't need to do anything special to make it work with SSR"

Comment: I can't figure out how to get / display any server data at all. Client hydration is fine (javascript) but the data doesn't appear in the body where I put it. So yeah, we obviously do need to do something special to make it work with SSR - and by work, actually do SSR not just make it do client hydration while in SSR mode. Did you ever find a solution? Because I'm thinking manually importing and setting up Firebase Admin is the only thing that will actually work.